Rollup + typescript + ReactJS only building .d.ts files and not .js files for everything except index.ts - why?
I am currently splitting apart a ReactJS+Tailwind app written in Typescript into a yarn v1 workspaces-based project. The idea is that we need to deploy one site many times with slight variations, so we want to use the mono repo pattern for managing as much of this as we can.
I managed to split apart the underlying components into a separate workspace, called packages/components. I have setup this "package" to be used by the web apps themselves.
Here is my rough structure for the workspaces project:
project/
  package.json
  packages/
    components/
      pacakage.json
      tsconfig.json
      rollup.config.js
      src/
        index.ts
        index.css
        components/
          atoms/
            Input.tsx
          molecules/
          organisms/
          templates/
  apps/
    admin/
    lander1/
    lander2/
    ...


In order to build the components package, I am using rollup.
So long as I export and import everything from the root of the components package, the setup works great. But I would really like to clean up the imports, so that instead of writing something like
import { Input } from 'components'

I can instead write
import { Input } from 'components/atoms'

or even
import { Input } from 'components/atoms/Input'

right now I would even take
import { Input } from 'components/components/atoms/Input'

but none of those options resolve in the apps projects, despite them otherwise being totally functional projects.
I notice that in the resulting dist directory (in packages/components) when I run yarn build (rollup -c), the only resulting .js file is index.js in the root. No matter how hard I have tried, only .d.ts files are ever generated for any other .tsx or .ts file. Doesn't matter if they are included and exported again in index.ts or not.
Here are the most relevant (parts) of the most important config files for the packages/components project. First, package.json:
{
  "name": "components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^5.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^26.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-multi-entry": "^6.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "rollup": "^4.20.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-ts": "^3.4.5",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0"
  }
}

Next, tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}


and finally, rollup.config.js:
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import multiEntry from '@rollup/plugin-multi-entry';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const projectRootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);
console.log('Project Root Directory:', projectRootDir);
const srcDir = path.resolve(projectRootDir, 'src');
console.log('src Directory:', srcDir);

export default {
  input: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
  output: [
    {
      dir: 'dist',
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      dir: 'dist',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    multiEntry(),
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'components', replacement: path.resolve(srcDir, 'components') },
      ],
    }),
    console.log('Alias Path:', path.resolve(srcDir, 'components')),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
      include: ["*.ts+(|x)", "**/*.ts+(|x)"],
      clean: true,
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: true,
    }),
  ],
  external: (source) => {
    // Specific external dependencies
    const specificExternals = ['react', 'react-dom'];

    // Check if the source is one of the specified externals or in node_modules
    return specificExternals.includes(source) || /node_modules/.test(source);
  },
};

console.log('Output Configuration:', JSON.stringify({
  dir: 'dist',
  format: ['cjs', 'esm'],
  sourcemap: true,
}, null, 2));

console.log('TypeScript Plugin Configuration:', JSON.stringify({
  tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
}, null, 2));

I have tried so many variations of all of these, especially rollup.config.js, everything from a something very simple to now trying to use multi entry plugin with glob-based paths.
Any suggestions for settings I need to trigger to fix the problem?
